# Values on a simulated bell curve in golang

Tags: math, go

My math is a bit elementary so I apologize for any assumptions in advance.

I want to fetch values that exist on a simulated bell curve. I don't want to actually create a bell curve or plot one, I'd just like to use a function that given an input value can tell me the corresponding Y axis value on a hypothetical bell curve.

Here's the full problem statement:

I am generating floating point values between 0.0 and 1.0.

0.50 represents 2.0 on the bell curve, which is the maximum. The values < 0.50 and > 0.50 start dropping on this bell curve, so for example 0.40 and 0.60 are the same and could be something like 1.8. 1.8 is arbitrarily chosen for this example, and I'd like to know how I can tweak this 'gradient'.

Right now Im doing a very crude implementation, for example, for any value > 0.40 and < 0.60 the function returns 2.0, but I'd like to 'smooth' this and gain more 'control' over the descent/gradient

Any ideas how I can achieve this in Go

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function for the formula. Use math.Exp for exponentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaussian function described here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function
has a bell-curve shape. Example of implementation :

```
package main
import (
    "math"
)

const (
    a = 2.0 // height of curve's peak
    b = 0.5 // position of the peak
    c = 0.1 // standart deviation controlling width of the curve 
            //( lower abstract value of c -> "longer" curve)
)

func curveFunc(x float64) float64 {
    return a *math.Exp(-math.Pow(x-b, 2)/(2.0*math.Pow(c, 2)))
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Just what I was looking for! I played with it a bit. Im having a hard time understanding c. i'd like the curveFunc to return 0.0 for both x=0.0 and x=1.0, so i should just try different values of c until i get that? what determines the 'slope' of the curve? (how rapidly it falls on either end?)

Comment: s/math.Pow(math.E, /math.Exp(/

Comment: Well it is my bad with description. by "longer curve" i meant slower falling(for example for c =1 the curve will fall faster than with c = 0.1). This function does not ever reach 0, but since float64 cannot represent ifinitely small fractions you can take such c that the function will in fact return 0 on x=0 and x=1(but you would have to play with c value).  But i recommend you another solution. You could move the peak to be 3 ( a = 3). Then calculate c from a regular equation when curveFunc(0) == 1 . When you get the c, just substract 1 from the function.

Comment: 2.0*math.Pow(c, 2) must be in brackets:
return a *math.Exp(-math.Pow(x-b, 2)/(2.0*math.Pow(c, 2)))  .

c is not an abstract value, it's a full width at half maximum - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum